# Using a number in an equation when a user inputs a certain word

Tags: python, variables, input, type-conversion

new to programming here.

I have an equation I'd like to use with user input data. I've successfully had it run when the user inputs a number.

However, I'm currently trying to make three words associated with one number. Then, when the user inputs that word, the associated number is used in the equation.

For example (will just use letters as variables here. I want A, B, and C to all equal the value 6. Then when user inputs either A, B, or C, the value 6 is used in equation z):

```py
A = B = C = 6

x = input("Enter number: ")

y = input("Enter A, B, or C: ")

z =(10 ** (float(x)-float(y)))

percent = z * 100
```

Then I know how to print the value of percent as a float with two decimal points. Just need input y to be converted to a float.

Thanks in advance. Hope the question was clear enough!

Comment: If they're all the same number, what's the point of asking for the word?

Comment: Use a dictionary. Look up the word the user enters in the dictionary to get the corresponding value.

Comment: If you define a dictionary like `lookup = {'A': 6, 'B': 6, 'C': 6}` you can then perform the lookup like `z =(10 ** (float(x)-float(lookup[y])))` - it's unclear why you'd want to do this, but this is how

Comment: Thanks everyone. Everything is in working order. Dictionary method does just what I need. As for why I wanted this, it's so a user can input an amino acid full-length name, three letter abbreviation, or single letter code and have its pKa used in the Henderson Hasselbalch equation.

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar said, use a dictionary:

```py
my_dict = {'A': 6, 'B': 6, 'C': 6}

x = input("Enter number: ")

y = input("Enter A, B, or C: ")

z =(10 ** (float(x)-float(my_dict[y])))

percent = z * 100
```